# Android Error handling - Sorry - The application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, validation, exception, forms

I've got it wrapped in a try catch, but the exception still trips that ugly screen.

```
 URL u = null;
    try {
      u = new URL(txturl.getText().toString());
        }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     ReportError(e,"Unable to connect to "+u);

    }
```

calls this:

```
    private void ReportError(Exception e, String message){
Display(message+" - "+ e.getMessage().toString());
System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+message+" - "+e.getMessage().toString());printStackTrace();
```

}

Any way around this. It happens on the Android 2.2 emulator with Eclipse and on my Sprint Hero.

Do I have to validate the form?

Thanks.

Comment: How about you show us the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to return after these exceptions. duh. sorry.